# Why Node.js cannot run my JavaScript code in the terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

[image]

Can anyone please tell me why my javascript code cannot be executed? What is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier?

Comment: This... really needs a lot more debugging work from your side. For instance: are you even in the right directory? Are you even in a proper shell? (because that `>` suggests you're in some kind of REPL, not actually in bash, zsh, or even windows `cmd` or something).

Comment: It seems you may already be in the `node` interactive shell, try to exit by pressing CTRL+C and then running `node index.js` again, from your bash terminal.

Comment: That's the Node REPL, not a shell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a `>` before your text cursor. This means that you're *already in Node*.

Right now, what's happening is you're telling Node to run the following JavaScript:

```js
node index.js
```

which, of course, is not valid JavaScript.

You need to exit Node so that the standard terminal is displayed, such as cmd or powershell (press Control-C a couple times)

[image]

*Then* you can type in `node index.js`. If you're in the same directory as the `index.js` file, it'll execute.

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  But this is a REALLY poor question - the OP simply doesn't know how to use VSCode, and/or doesn't understand the difference between a "command prompt" and a "NodeJS shell prompt".  I vote to close the question...

Comment: @paulsm4 We can do both... solve the problem and vote to close the question.